# How to create an array from values of another array

Tags: php

This is probably a question with a very simple answer but I am unable to figure it out. How could I write a foreach loop to add elements from an array to another array? Below I have array $A and I want to be able to write code to come up with something like $B from $A.

```
$A = array('0'=>array('name'=>'Oscar'),'1'=>array('name'=>'Jake'));

$B = array('0'=>'Oscar','1'=>'Jake');
```

Here is what I came up with, but it's not working.

```
$B = array();
foreach ($A as $element=>$data) {
    $B[] = $element['name'];
}
```

Comment: _I want to be able to write code to come up with something like $B from $A_ So YOU have to start by trying some code. If it does not work, show us then we can point you in the right direction

Comment: [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: Fair enough @RiggsFolly I've added what I have.

Comment: you're almost there, change `$element['name'];` to `$data['name'];`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$b = array_map(function($content) {
    return $content['name'];
}, $a);
```

`array_map` is a method with a callback that loops over an array and creates a new loop, depending on the return value in the `function`.

I use `array_map` instead of a `foreach` loop, because array methods of PHP are optimized and improve performance when used right.

Docs about `array_map` can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

---

What I always like to do, is visualize it for myself.

You can use multiple ways to visualize how the variable looks like and go from there. My personal favorites:

- `debugging` using `Xdebug`
- `print_r()`
- `var_dump()`